# How to remove substrings from a python list

Tags: python

Is there any list comprehension technique to get the below-desired result in a better way

```
a = ['hello', 'world', 'hello world', 'hello world how are', 'hello india']

final = set()
for i in a:
    for j in [x for x in a if x != i]:
        if i in j:
            final.add(i)
list(set(a)^final)
```

Comment: You could put a `break` inside the `if` - no point adding any item to `final` more than once.

Comment: This is a highly rated question, so I presume I’m the only dumb person here, but... Please find a way to indicate what it is you want with a question, rather than having us puzzle it out from your code.  That could be as simple as just printing the desired output, since you seem to be happy with the result, just not with the method.

Answer (score 4):

Shorter but not necessarily better:

```
print([x for x in a if not any(x in j for j in a if x != j)])
```

With removing of duplicates in the final list (resembles behavior from question):

```
print(list(set(x for x in a if not any(x in j for j in a if x != j))))
```

Comment: your code retains duplicate in output if present in the initial list while OP's solution doesn't do that

Comment: you can also use `filter`, which is basically the same: `list(filter(not any(element in other and element != other for other in a), set(a)))`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
set([i for i in a if not any(set(i) < set(j) for j in a)])
```